# Dlib image load error, unable to load image

Tags: ios, iphone, dlib

I am developing an iOs application in which I have implemented the Dlib library to get the facial landmark points in an image. Below is the code I have implemented.

```
dlib::frontal_face_detector detector = dlib::get_frontal_face_detector();
dlib::shape_predictor shapePredictor;
NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

NSString *landmarkdat = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%s",
    mainBundle.bundlePath,"shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat"]; 

dlib::deserialize(landmarkdat.UTF8String) >> shapePredictor;   
dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel> img;    
dlib::load_image(img,"001.png" );
```

But when I run the code in xcode 8.3 I am getting `error.dlib::image_load_error: Unable to open file`

Comment: Make sure you check **Copy items if needed** when you import the file

Comment: I have copied the file  to the project folder

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide bundle path for that image which worked for me.

```
    NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"jpg"];
    std::string fileName = [imagePath UTF8String];
    dlib::array2d<unsigned char> img;
    load_image(img, fileName);
```

Note : Add images directly to bundle dont add images to asset folder.